# COUNTIF with relative cell range in condition

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I want a Google sheets formula along the lines of

```
=countif(a4:a150;and(sum(e4:j4)<132;sum(e4:k4)>=132))
```

I.e., for each of the rows 4-150 (column A is not relevant), if the sum of columns E-J in that row is <132 and the sum of columns E-K in that row is >=132, then count that row with 1; in the end return the amount of rows that satisfy the condition.

Pseudo code:

```
count = 0
for 4 <= i <= 150:
    if (sum(Ei:Ji)<132 and sum(Ei:Ki)>=132):
       count = count+1
return count
```

However, `countif` does not accept complex conditions. I've been fiddling around with `arrayformula` and nestings of `sum` and `countif` for a while but can not find out which combination yields me the desired function structure that iterates over all rows, then checks the sum over a column range relative to that row and counts the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following formula in cell `A4`.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(
    ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(E4:J4),ROW(E4:J8)),ROW(E4:J8),E4:J8)<132)*
    ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(IF(COLUMN(E4:K4),ROW(E4:K8)),ROW(E4:K8),E4:K8)>=132),1,"Oh no!"))
```

*(The above formula assumes data is in `E4:K8`. Please adjust it to fit your data.)*

The **following formula** can be used as an alternative that **also warns** you when and if there are any **empty cells** in your data.

```
=IFERROR(ArrayFormula(IF(
    ArrayFormula(MMULT(E4:J8,TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(E4:J4))))<132)*
    ArrayFormula(MMULT(E4:K8,TRANSPOSE(SIGN(COLUMN(E4:K4))))>=132),1,"Oh no!")),"missing value")
```

Comment: This just returns 1 or "Oh no", but I want a count indicating how many rows in the range E4-K150 matched the condition.

Comment: As for the "Oh no", it can be changed to whatever you like. Furthermore. Sorry but I do not understand [your edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/revisions/137743/4): _"in the end return the amount of rows that satisfy the condition."_ In the end of what? Your original question was _"...then count that row with 1"_. This is what both formulas do. Please share a test sheet with expected results.

Comment: In the end of evaluating the whole formula. The 1/0 is the intermediate result for each row. Each row is just one iteration in the countif, which is supposed to be the outer function.

Comment: That is easy. Just wrap the formula with `SUM`. Meaning: `=SUM(the formula)`.

Comment: The way your original question was phrased gave the impression you were stuck on these intermediate steps _(the difficult part)_

Comment: This works. Thank you!

Comment: Glad it worked out. Please remember that sharing a sheet always helps.

Answer (score 1):

As you're only summing a few columns, you could do something like this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(ARRAYFORMULA((E4:E150+F4:F150+G4:G150+H4:H150+I4:I150+J4:J150)<132),ARRAYFORMULA((E4:E150+F4:F150+G4:G150+H4:H150+I4:I150+J4:J150+K4:K150)>=132))
```

Using `ARRAYFORMULA` with functions that already take a range gets overly complicated. I think this solves it for you fairly easily.

Hope that helps!

Comment: This will probably do the job, but I was hoping that there would be a more generic solution using the `sum` function, since I have several of these conditionals and some of the sums will be quite long.